# 4960 days in the Penalty Box

Tags: support, account-suspension

The [official blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) clearly says:

> Depending on the severity of the problem behavior — and at the complete discretion of the moderator — your account will be placed in timed suspension for **anywhere from 1 to 365 days**.

However.. (click to reach the profile)

[image: life sentence]

Obviously, something here is wrong - either the blog post needs an update or the time displayed is wrong?

Comment: 2025... Ouch...

Comment: @Lix yeah, more than murderers get in our country!

Comment: That's .. not a user. It's a temporal vortex that opens when humans dare to drink the blood of unicorns. Back away from it, slowly, but don't show it any fear, or [spaghettification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghettification) will surely follow.

Comment: As Tim says, that's not a real user. The suspension is meant to be that long.

Comment: He's bringing it up because _that user_ just _appeared_ to have spammed [this meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91157/can-we-have-drafts-for-moderator-messages), but it was the result of a merge on SU.

Comment: @Tim true about the spam here drawing my attention. Still confused though.. you say some new (unregistered?) user posted spam here on Meta; his account was then merged automatically with that.. spam center account.. and only then was nuked? Anyway, the "about me" text is confusing would be better to start with "Hi, I'm not really a person" like the good old Community account because on first sight (and second too, actually) it appears like ordinary person who just spam all across the network..

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd It originated on SU as 'web hosting' (first account), then went to lots of other sites. When 'web hosting' was merged on SU into the 'Deposit' account, all sites reflected that.

Comment: @Tim fair enough - learned something new (couple of things actually - Spaghettification might come in handy as well! :)) please close as dupe.

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd To be clear, it only exists on SU, it's not a network wide catch all. This should not have happened (which is a strong argument against individual sites collecting spam accounts instead of just destroying them on sight).

Comment: What?! Deposit used to be suspended until '89!

Comment: @Bobby 1989?! :D

Comment: @Tim wait.. so how did it happen then? The spammer stole identity of other account?? BTW he's [on a roll today](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127348/how-to-add-comments-in-stackoverflow/127351#127351)

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd: Mor like 2189. ;)

Comment: @Bobby guess that a merciful moderator arrived! :)

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd: Merciful moderators...wait, we've got such a being? ;P

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd A user named 'web hosting' showed up on SU. Then went to lots of other sites. When the mods merged 'webhosting' into 'Deposit' on SU, this affected every account the user had associated with SU. So, that's why it's showing up everywhere as 'Deposit'. Long story short, recent changes make keeping 'deposit' accounts around a bad idea.

Comment: @Tim thanks, this makes much more sense now.

Comment: @TimPost: No, don't take Deposit away...I get a warm and fuzzy feeling inside everytime I see it. :(

Comment: @Bobby You need to get out more.

Comment: @TimPost: Dude, I was 'out there'...last week or so...

Comment: @Pat wrong way to remove this. We should reopen and close again as dupe, since I've already voted to close as dupe can't use my hammer.

Comment: Oh, wait! I have an idea.

Comment: I think the OP-hammer will still work.

Comment: Awesome, it worked. Thanks @Pat! :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Deposit user is a culmination of several hundreds of spam users (468, at last count). Some of the spammers were already suspended before merge, I assume merge adds the suspension term of the user to the existing suspension term.

Comment: Yeah.. so is it your doing? :)

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd hah!