# Increase close reasons from 400 to 512 characters?

Tags: feature-request, comments, vote-to-close, user-interface

The **what** is clear: To allow the entire StackExchange network to be *inherently a little bit more polite while remaining helpful*.

The **how** is clear: To extend the *Off-Topic Close Reasons* by 112 characters.

**The simple question is:** *What does it take to make this happen?*

**The long question:**

At the moment, close reasons are limited to 400 characters. This makes it hard to write polite close reasons and results in rather brusque and curt messages that *does* alienate new users. For example, we would like to change the following close reason from AskUbuntu from this:

> This question has been asked before and already has an answer.

To something like this:

> We've searched AskUbuntu and found that your question already has an answer. Please check here: [link]. If this doesn't answer your question, please reword your question to explain in more depth.

So what does it take to increase the allowable responses from 400 to 512 characters?

Does it take:

- a highly voted question on meta.StackExchange.com?
- rallying all the users on all sites in the network?
- me flying into NY and banging a magnum bottle of Champagne on Joel
  Spolsky's desk?

*Thank you?*

Comment: As far as system messages being slightly more polite, I agree.

Comment: Does the user whose post is flagged offensive actually see the flag description? My impression is that the description is only seen by the one raising the flag, as a description of what the flag is for.

Comment: Pictures please of you banging that bottle on the desk of Mr. Spolsky.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: I don't know about all of the sites, but on AskUbuntu, they show up as canned "comments".

Comment: @Fabby - are you sure about that? The flags from the review queues do, but they're not offensive flags. Do you have an example of this?

Comment: @ChrisF: As I'm not a mod, I asked one of the mods for the exact term and he told me "Off-Topic Close Reasons".  I'm taking about "the canned comments that the user sees"  What would be the *technical, internal SE term*  for that then?

Comment: @Fabby - yes, those are the comments from the review queues **NOT** from offensive flags.

Comment: I am confused. Could you make it more clear which particular system message you want to extend by which text? It is not clear to me which message "no service for you" is supposed to represent. And which additional 112 characters do you wish to add?

Comment: @HugoRune: Currently the standard close reasons for the beginning user **just look like**: *No service for you!* then something more polite and helpful...  ;-)

Comment: Which close reason looks like this? Do you mean the options I get when clicking on "flag"? Or the options I get when clicking on "flag"/"it should be closed..."? Neither one conveys to me anything like "no service for you". A screenshot with the text you refer to highlighted would really help here. Or even just a direct quote.

Comment: @HugoRune What I'm trying to say is that they're not polite! :(  I want them to be polite, but there is not enough space in the system to add "I'm sorry, but..." and "Please, ..."

Comment: I get that you don't think they are polite, but I really actually do not know which messages you refer to (though I do have some guesses). I'm not trying to be coy here, could you just quote the text you are talking about?

Comment: All of them except one!  ;) E.g. "This question has been asked before and already has an answer."

Comment: "Dear Sir/Madam user123456789: We are very sorry to inform you that your question has been closed for being too awesome for Stack Exchange to handle. Please accept our sincere apologies for any inconvenience you may have experienced with respect to this. Looking forward to hearing from you. Sincerely yours, [close voters names]"

Comment: @gnat "Looking forward to hearing from you, except that we will not be notified of your comment."

Comment: @Fundamental given that this is slightly tweaked version of [suspension message](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91157/can-we-have-drafts-for-moderator-messages#comment368058_91157 "'Dear Sir/Madam user123456789: As a moderator I am very sorry to inform you that your account is temporarily suspended because of low-quality contributions. Please accept our sincere apologies for any inconvenience you may have experienced with respect to this. Looking forward to hearing from you. Sincerely yours, [moderator name]'") I drafted a while ago, your addition certainly belongs :)

Comment: @Fabby, I'm 100% behind ways to make it feel better.  As to what it'll take? All those things, especially the champagne. But start here: can you edit to be more specific about what specific messages you'd change (from what to what)?

Comment: @Jaydles: Thanks you very much. :-) Can I do that in a link separate from the message itself (E.g. http://paste.ubuntu.com/9762393/ ) and then inform you in a comment, or do you prefer a link in the message so it's easier for you to communicate internally?  Or do you prefer an answer?  Or something else entirely??? (I obviously prefer separately from the question as not to distract the message from the solution)

Comment: @Fabby, I think editing the question is the best - your question implies a *specific* change would help, but isn't quite specific enough to consider it.  Also, if you haven't seen it, check out this post: we *do* care a lot about this issue: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/06/the-war-of-the-closes/

Comment: @Jaydles: Still reading the article you provided.  Thanks for that: it provides some historical background for my mindset.  Furthermore, as I've run into trouble before editing my question on-line, I'm now editing it off-line and will add all of the changes in one go!  (Good enough?) :-)

Comment: @Jaydles: Heads-up!  ;-)

Comment: Sorry, but I do not think a Q&A site should apologize to users who misuse it. Comments should be polite, not close banners. They should be short and to the point.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Thank you for your feed-back. In the couple of months I've been around one of the sites in our network as a very active replier, I've seen *some* misuse, but most of the time it's just *misunderstanding*.  Mostly to not reading the help pages, but that's the nature of the beast.  I'm not saying that the titles for the mods, reviewers, ... should become overly long, just the canned comments that the end-user will immediately or at the end of the process should see below his/her/its question.

Comment: I understand your point, but close banner starting with "We're sorry but..." sounds too... meekly to me. Users will think the veteran users owe them something, and it might just lead to more confusion in the long run. (plus, who are the "we" exactly? The users who closed the question?)

Comment: @ShadowWizard "We" = the entire community on the StackExchange network: veterans *and newbies* alike.  (We were *all* newbies once upon a time) As to confusion: Please butt in and ensure the "nice answer" is *not* confusing.  Leave a comment, add your own answer, ... ;-)

Comment: Please ask a new question. There is a highly upvoted answer that would be turned pointless if you change the question like this. (without answers, it's sometimes legit to ask something totally different, but not when there are answers already. The site won't break due to extra question :))

Comment: @ShadowWizard: have a look at the revisions, please? (Last edit was done after moderator made exactly the same remarks you're giving, so basically I'm reverting)

Comment: No idea what you mean. Changing the question to something totally different is just wrong on the verge of rude. If you don't want the question to stay you can flag and ask to delete it.

Comment: Just a note "This question is effectively an advertisement with no disclosure. It is not useful or relevant, but promotional." is not a close reason, is a flag which would result in deletion of the post isofact. Is not a valid close reason.

Comment: @Braiam: I've asked for the question to be deleted. I'll change the term in the new question I will be asking...  Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: @ShadowWizard the question is the same. All that was removed was the extra verbiage which was not really adding anything to the main point which was making the close reasons longer.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I agree with Terdon. The question hadn't changed, it was just a *lot* more concise than the monster this thing mutated into. The existing answer still applies.

Comment: @terdon OK, let's wait for the flag to kick in. The SE employee handling it would either agree with the OP here and rollback again to his last revision, or delete this whole thing and let him post new question from scratch.

Comment: I agree with @ShadowWizard. No edit wars here...  Let's take it up in a chat room with a Moderator and talk like adults.  ;-)

Comment: I don't like apologising to them when they are the ones using offensive language.

Comment: @Tim: You're not apologising... You're *flagging* them!  ;-)

Comment: @Fabby: *"We're sorry, but the wording of this question is likely to be deemed inappropriate for polite discourse by most of the users in the [szSitename] community."* Just get rid of the sorry part.

Comment: @Tim: I've asked for the question to be deleted.  I would like to start afresh as this has evolved into semantics, whereas my original question was just about extending 400 bytes to 512 bytes...

Comment: "12-yo native English speaker" ಠ_ಠ People of any given age will have a wide range of abilities in different areas. I don't think generalizing to say a group of people all have some level of skill or knowledge in a given area is fair, and when that is used to imply that many people's skill levels are poor it comes across to me as rude, or even dehumanizing.

Comment: Though it may be tangential to the actual point of your post, I have to agree with @bjb568 here; I hate to hinge on little things, but I think the vocabulary of an average 12-year-old native English speaker is a lot broader than you seem to assume here. Your point comes off a bit ad hominem with phrasing like that, and it's not doing your argument any favors.

Comment: @bjb568: completely revamped...

Comment: @AstroCB: completely revamped.

Comment: Voted to reopen.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: That's a surprise!  (But a pleasant one!)  Thanks!  :-)

Comment: @Fabby disagreeing with the request/idea doesn't mean it should be closed. :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard :D There are not many people as impartial as you!  ;-)

Answer (score 21):

The best that you can hope for in a close reason is a neutral tone.  No matter how much you try, you're not going to convince the author that the closure is a *positive* thing if it means that people can't post answers.

The **primary** goal, is to communicate to the author why the question is closed, and what they have to do to fix it.

That's about as welcoming as a close question can get.  So long as you're not **rude** to askers their primary concern will be the fact **that their question is closed**.  Not the tone of the close message.

What the askers actually want is to **know what to do about it.** They have a problem to solve, and even **they** just want the information.  They probably don't feel like taking the time to read extra patronizing.

Comment: The difference is in how people feel about their closed question.

Comment: Personally when someone tries to tell me that I'm an idiot in what they think is being extremely "polite", it more often than not just comes off as insincere and even more offensive than dry facts.

Comment: @Emrakul So, judging by how differently people will feel about the closed question with extra patronizing tacked on, you're saying that there is no difference?>

Comment: @Emrakul In my experiences the *vast* majority of people don't even bother to read the (entire) close reason.  They're upset *that* their question is closed, not because the specific wording of why their question was closed offended them.

Comment: @Sam There's a difference between patronizing and respectful. A _distinct_ difference. Our options aren't "purely informative" or "patronizing." That's a false dichotomy.

Comment: @Servy It's not just about the close reason, but the tone of comments handling the question.

Comment: @Emrakul This particular feature request is in fact just about the close reason.

Comment: I agree that is *shouldn't* matter, but I think the reality is that "We can't help you. You did it wrong by doing [thing]." is a lot less likely to motivate another try than "We can help you just as soon as you can [do opposite of thing]." The info is the same, but one sounds like "I'm eager to help you - here's what to do" and one sounds like "I've judged you, and found you wanting."  Humans are weird.

Comment: Let's agree to disagree: **"You're fired"** is neutral.  However *"Unfortunately, we're downsizing, but we're letting the people without children, unmarried, still living with their parents go first and we're paying for outplacement so that you can find another job as quickly as possible"* is not.  And what I'm trying to accomplish, is the latter. :-)

Comment: @Servy: yes and no. The real world out there doesn't come in shades of grey: it comes in full colour! ;-)

Comment: @Jaydles: Thank you!  Humans are not weird: they're *alien!*  ;-)

Comment: @Fabby  **but we're letting the people without children, unmarried, still living with their parents go first**  Yes, that's right, insult the more when you fire them.   Shame on them for still living in their parents house and/or not getting married.  **and we're paying for outplacement so that you can find another job as quickly as possible** There's not a debate over whether users find it more friendly if there's a substantive difference in how their question is closed.  The difference between getting fired with and without outplacement is not an analogy for the question here

Comment: Like I said: *Let's agree to disagree*.  It's not a black&white world out there: it's full colour and I'm yellow and you're purple!